How do I get attributes of the protected areas in Cuba using the package wdpar in R?
I am trying to download spatial information and attributes of protected areas in Cuba from the World Database on Protected Areas by using the package wdpar in R. To download the data I use the function wdpa_fetch and indicate that I need information for Cuba with the ISO-3 code "CUB".
library(wdpar)
CUB_raw_pa <- wdpa_fetch("CUB", wait = TRUE, download_dir = rappdirs::user_data_dir("wdpa"))

This creats an object with one variable containing information about the multipolygones of the protected areas in Cuba but does not provide any variables containing additional information about these areas.
resulting objected in R.
How can I solve the issue and obtain additional information about protected areas in Cuba using the package wdpar?
If I use the same code for other countries, for example Germany ("DEU"), the same code works and I obtain an object with 29 variables. If I downloaded the same data manually from the website of the World Database on Protected Areas additional information about protected areas in Cuba is available.

Welcome to SO! I believe that's actually a problem with the package itself, I suggest you contact the maintainers. A possible workaround is to download the complete WDPA database, which has a country variable. You can then filter the database for the desired countries.

Thanks, @FAmorim, for your quick answer. I contacted the author and will work with the database directly.

The autor of the package wdpar, Jeffrey O Hanson, fixed the bug and will update the package on CRAN in the following days.
